# Does PyCharm code inspection incorrectly warn on regular expression equivalents?

Tags: python, regex, pycharm, code-inspection

PyCharm's (2022.1.2 Community Edition) code inspection complains that I could write some of my regular expressions as more simple equivalents. Considering unicode characters though (and why wouldn't I?), they are not equivalent. Am I mistaken, or is this simply a bug?

Example:

```py
import re

# complains: "'[a-zA-Z0-9_]' can be simplified to '\w'"
pattern1 = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]")
pattern2 = re.compile(r"\w")
print(bool(pattern1.match("é")))  # False
print(bool(pattern2.match("é")))  # True
```

Comment: In Python, these are not equivalent. However, it is true that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` = `(?a)\w` (`\w` with `re.A` / `re.ASCII` flag).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Would you answer my core question whether this is a bug in Pycharm with yes then?

Comment: This will still not have any value. The value is in understanding what `\w` matches in Python, and I have explained this quite extensively in another post. You can log a bug fix request/issue for PyCharm where appropriate.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I appreciate your answer, though it addresses a question that I did not raise. I was explicitly wondering whether PyCharm has a reason to warn me in that case without any indication of an ASCII flag. To me it just feels like a bug in that linter, and if I don't find a reason, I will report this behaviour at JetBrains.

Comment: I have no idea what your settings for all that are. The point is that in Python `re`, `\w` by default is not equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` **but** in Java, PHP they ARE equal. So, that may not be a bug. The linked post is just another way of saying "*the message you see it not correct when using Python `re`*", and it already is an answer for this question.

Comment: I am working with Python's `re`, and the code inspection is aware of that (see my question). If you are not aware of PyCharm's code inspection, you may just not be the right person to answer this question even though it is related to regular expressions ;)

Comment: follow up the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54668/Incorrect-warning-code-inspection-proposes-non-equivalent-simplifications-given-Unicode